# Cell Array or Multi-Subscripted Array?

Tags: matlab

The following piece of code works when data is passed as a `1x50 array`.
(Data is in fact a struct that passes several other parameters too). In the `1x50` case a `4x1` array of parameters is returned for each i (the value of `de.nP` is 600).

However I want to change it so that I can pass a matrix of data say `d` dates so that the matrix has dimension `dx50`. This will then return a `4xd` array for each i.

My question is should I use a cell array or a 3D array to store the values?
Seems to me both methods could do the job?

```
for i=1:de.nP
    betas(:,i)=NSS_betas(P1(:,i),data);
end
```

Going further into the code I will need to use

```
Params=vertcat(betas,P1);
```

Where `P1` is a `2x1` array. So for each date (i) I need to concatenate the contents of P(1) to all the betas for that date.

Will this affect the choice of whether to use cellarray or 3D array?

It seems to me cellarray is better suited to vectorised code (Which is what I am trying to use as much as possible) but 3D array might be easier to use with functions like `vertcat`?

Here is the whole code

```
mats=[1:50];
mats2=[2 5 10 30];
betaTRUE=[5 -2 5 -5 1 3; 4 -3 6 -1 2 4];
for i=1:size(betaTRUE,1)
    yM(i,:)=NSS(betaTRUE(i,:),mats);
    y2(i,:)=NSS(betaTRUE(i,:),mats2);
end
dataList=struct('yM',yM,'mats',mats,'model',@NSS,'mats2',mats2,'y2',y2);
de=struct('min',[0; 2.5],'max',      [2.5;5],'d',2,'nP',200,'nG',300,'ww',0.1,'F',0.5,'CR',0.99,'R',0,'oneElementfromPm',1);
beta=DElambdaVec(de,dataList,@OF);




function [output]=DElambdaVec(de,data,OF)

    P1=zeros(de.d,de.nP);
    Pu=zeros(de.d,de.nP);

 for i=1:de.d
     P1(i,:)=de.min(i,1)+(de.max(i,1)-de.min(i,1))*rand(de.nP,1);
 end


 P1(:,1:de.d)=diag(de.max);
 P1(:,de.d+1:2*de.d)=diag(de.min);

 for i=1:de.nP
     betas(:,i)=NSS_betas(P1(:,i),data);
 end

 Params=vertcat(betas,P1);

 Fbv=NaN(de.nG,1);
 Fbest=realmax;



 F=zeros(de.nP,1);
 P=zeros(de.nP,1);


 for i=1:de.nP 

    F(i)=OF(Params(:,i)',data);

    P(i)=pen(P1(:,i),de,F(i));
    F(i)=F(i)+P(i);


 end

 [Fbest indice] =min(F);
 xbest=Params(:,indice);
 %vF=vF+vP;

%NaN(de.nG,de.nP);
Col=1:de.nP; 

for g=1:de.nG
    P0=P1;
    rowS=randperm(de.nP)';
    colS=randperm(4)';
    RS=circshift(rowS,colS(1));
    R1=circshift(rowS,colS(2));
    R2=circshift(rowS,colS(3));
    R3=circshift(rowS,colS(4));

%mutate
Pm=P0(:,R1)+de.F*(P0(:,R2)-P0(:,R3));
%extra mutation
if de.R>0 
    Pm=Pm+de.r*randn(de.d,de.nP);
end

%crossover
PmElements=rand(de.d,de.nP)<de.CR;
%mPv(MI)=mP(Mi);
if de.oneElementfromPm
   Row=unidrnd(de.d,1,de.nP);
   ExtraPmElements=sparse(Row,Col,1,de.d,de.nP);
   PmElements=PmElements|ExtraPmElements;
end

P0_Elements=~PmElements;
Pu(:,RS)=P0(:,RS).*P0_Elements+PmElements.*Pm;

for i=1:de.nP
betasPu(:,i)=NSS_betas(Pu(:,i),data);
end



ParamsPu=vertcat(betasPu,Pu);
flag=0;
for i=1:de.nP

    Ftemp=OF(ParamsPu(:,i)',data);
    Ptemp=pen(Pu(:,i),de,F(i));
    Ftemp=Ftemp+Ptemp;

    if Ftemp<=F(i);
        P1(:,i)=Pu(:,i);
        F(i)=Ftemp;
        if Ftemp < Fbest
        Fbest=Ftemp; xbest=ParamsPu(:,i); flag=1;
        end
    else
        P1(:,i)=P0(:,i);
    end    
end

if flag
    Fbv(g)=Fbest;
end

end

output.Fbest=Fbest; output.xbest=xbest; output.Fbv=Fbv;

end


function penVal=pen(mP,pso,vF)

minV=pso.min;
maxV=pso.max;
ww=pso.ww;

A=mP-maxV;
A=A+abs(A);

B=minV-mP;
B=B+abs(B);

C=ww*((mP(1,:)+mP(2,:))-abs(mP(1,:)+mP(2,:)));
penVal=ww*sum(A+B,1)*vF-C;


end


function betas=NSS_betas(lambda,data)

mats=data.mats2';
lambda=lambda;
yM=data.y2';
nObs=size(yM,1);
G= [ones(nObs,1) (1-exp(-mats./lambda(1)))./(mats./lambda(1)) ((1-exp(-     mats./lambda(1)))./(mats./lambda(1))-exp(-mats./lambda(1))) ((1-exp(-   mats./lambda(2)))./(mats./lambda(2))-exp(-mats./lambda(2)))];

betas=G\yM;

end
```

Comment: your question is quite incoherent to me, you mention there is some array input, you would like to  expand, then some variables pop up that you would like to process. This makes it not that easy to judge what would be the best approach imo..

Comment: OK I added the rest of the code so that it can be seen in context. I've never dealt with anything more than a 2D array (matrix) so I'm just trying to get my head round 3D arrays. If its still not clear I am happy to clarify further.

Comment: still not clear, what's the input that's now `1x50`? What is the change you want? What are the essential parts of the code? what do you mean by 'This will then return a 4xd array for each i.' What is `i` in that case? What are the consequences on that piece of code if you feed it a `dx50` input? I didn't ask for full code, just to clarify what you want.. if you expect answers, make it easy on the answerers..

Comment: OK I have added all the code now. The first set of code is the script that calls the function. Sorry it's 1*4 not (1*50) that is used here (1*50 is used later). It the set of dates (mats2 in dataList)and the corresponding rates which are in y2 also in data List. These are passed to NSS_betas() along with each guess set of P1. NS_betas() is simply a sull spec simultaneous equation and returns 4 betas for each set of mats2 and y2. This works fine when the mats2 and y2 are passed one at a time, but when I try to pass multiple sets of mats2 and y2 simultaneously, there is a problem because

Comment: betas(:,i)is not big enough to hold the data anymore. So I just want to know the best way to expand betas? Should I make it a 3D array eg betas(h,i,j)? Or should I use a cell array? Given that NSS_betas is essentially returning an array block of data at a time I don't see how  a 3D array could be used (but I could be wrong) and was therefore wondering if something like a cellarray might be better instead?

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick will require extensive recoding in the rest of the function though!

```
betas=zeros(4,size(data.y2,1),de.nP);
 for i=1:de.nP
 betas(:,:,i)=NSS_betas(P1(:,i),data);
 end
```